# В динамически созданном imageview уменьшается загружаемое через Picasso изображение

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

Такая незадача, не возьму в толк в чем дело.
Создаются динамически imageview, в них загружаются изображения, используя Picasso. Изображение сжимается по высоте и ширине. Подскажите, что не так?

```
for (int i = 0; i < portfolio.size(); i++) {
    LinearLayout portfolioLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.PortfolioLayout);

    // Добавляем новый ImageView
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(masterDetails.this);
    imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    imageView.setMinimumHeight(100);
    imageView.setMinimumWidth(100);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
    portfolioLayout.addView(imageView);
    Picasso.with(masterDetails.this).load(portfolio.get(0).preview_path).into(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Вы не пояснили как вы хотите чтоб картинка отображалась. У пикассо есть методы типа resize  и fit

Comment: Нужно чтобы картинка отображалась как есть, ее фактический размер

Comment: Попробовал fit . Не помогло.

Comment: Попробуйте тогда слушатель окончания загрзки повесить и в нём назначить для ImageView размеры согласно размерам скачанной картинки